# jsTree change icon of child in XML populated jsTree

Tags: xml, jstree

I populate a tree with XML. Is there a way to change the icons of the childs?

[image]

Accessories is a main group, it should have a folder icon, but i want something else for the childs forther if there is another group so if the child is not a leaf it should still keep the folder icon.

Comment: You can use types plugin - http://www.jstree.com/documentation/types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just have to use `icon=''` in the `name` tag.